# MongoDB continue from current position after lost connection

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Hi I am having trouble keeping connection with my MongoDB and it ends up interrupting my program when it loses connection, how would I go about continuing to print from the last place that I lost connection at, I keep a count of the index but how do I use that count to start from that position in the cursor

```
using (server.RequestStart(db))
{
    var cursor = col.FindAll();
    foreach (var item in cursor)
    {
        //code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you having trouble keeping your connection to MongoDB open? Are you losing your network connection in the middle of the query? Are you timing out?

In general the only way to reliably restart a query is if the results are sorted and you use a query on the restart to skip over documents you already processed (in other words, skip over those documents where the sort key is less than or equal to the last document processed).

You probably don't need to call RequestStart. The only time you ever need to call RequestStart is if you want to ensure that a sequence of database operations all occur on the same connection (which is only needed in unusual circumstances).

Comment: I have over a million records which i am verifying against another database, but i am limited to verifying a specific amount every hour so it pauses for up to an hour at a time and then continues from where i was at. Would you be able to give me an example of the syntax of using the sort key to continue from the last record.

Comment: I Think i got it working using "cursor.Skip = i;" when it times out/loses connection, let me know if i am leaning in the wrong direction, Thanks Robert.